# Change imageview Onclick(View v)

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

I have a few imageview with onClick properties on it. I want to change the image when imageview is clicked. The image name comes from a string array.

This is my onClick method on MainActivity

```
public void kartu_klik(View v)
{
    //GET THE CARD'S NAME FROM STRING ARRAY
    int a = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
    String image_name = kartu[a];
    int image = getResources().getIdentifier(image_name, "drawable", "package.name");

    //GET IMAGE ID
    int id = v.getId();
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

    //CHANGE IMAGE
    img.setImageResource(image );
}
```

And this is the ImageView XML

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_11"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="kartu_klik"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />
```

The image doesn't change, but it disappears instead.

Comment: Log `kartu[a]` and make sure it has value

Comment: yes it has, I have toast it and there is no problem with it.

Comment: does `v.setImageResource(image)` work?

Comment: @Ali Sheikhpour no it's not. nothing happens.

Comment: Log "image" and make sure it has value. if not, try `getPackageName()` or `getActivity().getPackageName()` instead of "package.name"